Pass subnet ids from 2 VNETs to be used in network ACLs for an event hub namespace in Terraform
I am trying to deploy an event hub namespace with networking ACLs for two VNETs with their subnets being allowed.  I seem to running into issues when tryign to pass the subnet_ids inline.
Terraform event hub namespace module
 locals {
  networks_rules = {
    subnet_ids = "${var.allowed_subnet_ids}"
    cidrs      = "${var.allowed_cidrs}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "eventhub-namespace" {
  name                = var.eventhub_ns_name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags                = var.tags

  sku                      = var.eventhub_sku
  capacity                 = var.eventhub_ns_throughput
  auto_inflate_enabled     = var.auto_inflate.enabled
  maximum_throughput_units = var.auto_inflate.maximum_throughput_units
  zone_redundant           = var.eventhub_zone_redundant

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  dynamic "network_rulesets" {
    for_each = var.network_rules_enabled ? [local.networks_rules] : []
    iterator = rules

    content {
      default_action                 = var.network_rules_default_action
      public_network_access_enabled  = var.public_network_access_enabled
      trusted_service_access_enabled = var.network_trusted_service_access_enabled

      dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
        for_each = rules.value.subnet_ids
        content {
          subnet_id                                       = virtual_network_rule.value
          ignore_missing_virtual_network_service_endpoint = false
        }
      }

      dynamic "ip_rule" {
        for_each = rules.value.cidrs
        content {
          ip_mask = ip_rule.value
          action  = "Allow"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output "eventhub-namespace_id" {
  value = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhub-namespace.id
}

varaibles.tf
The cidr on the ip_rules will not change from resource to resource so i can pass these in as default.  However, the vnets will change and their associated subnets within them.
variable "allowed_cidrs" {
  description = "List of CIDR to allow access to that EventHub Namespace."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32"]
}

variable "allowed_subnet_ids" {
  description = "Subnet IDs to allow access to that EventHub Namespace."
  type        = list(string)
  default = []
}

main.tf
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm-vnet" {
  name                = var.vm_vnet
  resource_group_name = "${module.lab-net-rg.resource_group_name}"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks-vnet" {
  name                = var.aks_vnet
  resource_group_name = "${module.lab-net-rg.resource_group_name}"
}

module "event-hub" {
  source = "./modules/eventhub"

  eventhub_ns_name   = var.eventhub_ns_name
  resource_group_name = module.lab-paas-rg.resource_group_name
  location            = local.location
  tags                = local.paas-tags

  allowed_subnet_ids = [
    "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks-vnet.subnets.*.id}",
    "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.subnets.*.id}"
    ]

  depends_on = [module.lab-paas-rg]

}

This works if i do not pass in the subnet_ids, but i would like to create them when the event hub is deployed.
Error message:
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on eventhub.tf line 9, in module "event-hub":
│    9:   allowed_subnet_ids = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks-vnet.subnets.*.id}"
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Based on the documentation, I would say you need something like allowed_subnet_ids = concat(data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks-vnet.subnets, data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.subnets).

Can you try modifying like this data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks-vnet.subnets[*].id under allowed_subnet_ids block. @NickP


Error: Unsupported attribute │ │ on eventhub.tf line 9, in module "event-hub": │ 9: allowed_subnet_ids = "${data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks-vnet.subnets.*.id}" │ │ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

Error "Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value" occurs as terraform does not supports accessing the string values if you pass like
${data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.subnets.*.id}.
As suggested by @Marko E, you can go with the concat() function to achieve the expected outcome.
Alternatively, you can also use flatten() function available in terraform that helps to convert the output of a data block of virtual network to a list of string values as shown below.
Note: Replace flatten() with concat() if you want to use the concat() function approach.
allowed_subnet_ids = flatten([ 
   data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.subnets.*.id, 
   data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.subnets.*.id 
])

main.tf:
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name = "Jahnavi"
}
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm-vnet" {
  name                = "vnet1"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks-vnet" {
  name                = "vnet2"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
}

module "event-hub" {
  source = "./modules/eventhub"

  eventhub_ns_name   = "sampleehubjah"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location

  allowed_subnet_ids = flatten([ 
     data.azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.subnets.*.id, 
     data.azurerm_virtual_network.vm-vnet.subnets.*.id 
 ])

}

eventhub.tf:
provider "azurerm"{
   features{}
 }
 locals {
  networks_rules = {
    subnet_ids = "${var.allowed_subnet_ids}"
    cidrs      = "${var.allowed_cidrs}"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "eventhub-namespace" {
  name                = "sampleehubjah"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name


  sku                      = "Standard"
  capacity                 = 2

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  dynamic "network_rulesets" {
    for_each = var.network_rules_enabled ? [local.networks_rules] : []
    iterator = rules

    content {
      default_action                 = "allow"
      public_network_access_enabled  = var.public_network_access_enabled
     # trusted_service_access_enabled = var.network_trusted_service_access_enabled

      dynamic "virtual_network_rule" {
        for_each = rules.value.subnet_ids
        content {
          subnet_id                                       = virtual_network_rule.value
          ignore_missing_virtual_network_service_endpoint = false
        }
      }

      dynamic "ip_rule" {
        for_each = rules.value.cidrs
        content {
          ip_mask = ip_rule.value
          action  = "Allow"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

output "eventhub-namespace_id" {
  value = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.eventhub-namespace.id
}

variables.tf:
variable "allowed_cidrs" {
  description = "List of CIDR to allow access to that EventHub Namespace."
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["10.0.0.0/32", "10.0.0.1/32"]
}

variable "allowed_subnet_ids" {
  description = "Subnet IDs to allow access to that EventHub Namespace."
  type        = list(string)
  default = []
}
variable "network_rules_enabled" {
  description = "Enable for EventHub"
  type        = bool
  default     = false 
}

Deployment succeeded:



These still do not work for me, it looks like you have network rules disabled, so it will bypass the network virtual_network_ruleset block.  Same error with unsupported attribute
Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on eventhub.tf line 11, in module "spexs-event-hub":
│   11:     data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets.*.id
│
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

I was able to get it to work, with first looping through the subnets on the VNETs to obtain a subnet data block.
data "azurerm_subnet" "vnet-subnets" {   name                 = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets[count.index]   virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name   resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.resource_group_name   count                = length(data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.subnets) }

Then pass that down to the module:
allowed_subnet_ids = flatten([     data.azurerm_subnet.vnet-subnets.*.id,     data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnets.*.id   ])
